# AppFabric shutdown

Tags: sql-server, appfabric

We have implemeted appfabric caching in ASP.Net application.
Somtimes AppFabric shutdown in-between and throws below error.

```
AppFabric Caching service crashed.{Lease with external store expired: Microsoft.Fabric.Federation.ExternalRingStateStoreException: Renew lease failed ---> Microsoft.Fabric.Data.ExternalStoreException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ConfigStoreException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean& marsCapable)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SqlServerCustomProvider.BeginTransaction()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SqlServerCustomProvider.BeginTransaction()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ExternalConfigStore.BeginTransaction()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ExternalConfigStore.BeginTransaction()
   at Microsoft.Fabric.Data.ExternalStoreAuthority.UpdateNode(NodeInfo nodeInfo, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Fabric.Data.ExternalStoreAuthority.UpdateNode(NodeInfo nodeInfo, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Fabric.Federation.SiteNode.PerformExternalRingStateStoreOperations(Boolean& canFormRing, Boolean isInsert, Boolean isJoining)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reason for above exception was, DataCache.Put method was getting called many times for each user.